# include attachment when sending email

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

my app is sending email with an attachment but the problem is it send the email but with no attachment. The file does exist in SDcard and i can detach it and view the file.

Here is the code **Email.java**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "" });
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file://mnt/sdcard/fun/itisfun.csv"));    
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
i.setType("message/rfc822");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"gmail :"));
```

Here are the permissions i have tried in **Menifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></permission>
```

i will appreciate your help.

Comment: try to use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try out as below :

> ```
>        File pngDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"fun/"); 
>             if (!pngDir.exists())
>             {
>                 pngDir.mkdirs();
>             }              
>             File pngfile=new File(pngDir,"itisfun.csv");
>             Uri pngUri =Uri.fromFile(pngfile);
>             Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>             emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
>             emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{""});
>             emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
>             emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
>             emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,pngUri);
>             emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
>             startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is code I use to attach files to an email (Gmail app):

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, 
            new String[]{emailTo});
        //has to be an ArrayList
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
        for (String file : filePaths)
        {
            File fileIn = new File(file);
            Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
            uris.add(u);
        }
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailText);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail via"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailSignature);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, toSenders);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subjectText);
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, messageText+"\n\n"+emailSignature); 

emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
File bitmapFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
        "/"+FOLDER_NAME+"/picture.jpg");
myUri = Uri.fromFile(bitmapFile);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, myUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send your email in:"));
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

```
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("text/plain");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "" });
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse("file://sdcard/fun/itisfun.csv"));    
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
                i.setType("message/rfc822");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i,"gmail :"));
```

Comment: no i have remove the /mnt from the path file://sdcard/fun/itisfun.csv

Comment: This gives toast "Permission denied for the attachment."